# Is it possible to run sonatype/nexus3 docker container on macOS?

Tags: macos, docker, nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to start Maven repository as Docker container with this command:

```bash
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

When I do it on my Windows 10 host, everything is fine.

When I try the same on my macOS host, I get a lot of errors in logs. Eventually, Nexus3 starts somehow, but when I try to open http://localhost:8081/ it stacks forever on the initializing screen.

Is there any way to start Nexus on macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. It looks line now (13.09.2021) the desidion is to use [klo2k/nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/klo2k/nexus3) version of Nexus on ARM

Answer (score -1):

I use also this image and it's work fine on my config (macOS Big Sur with Docker Desktop 3.6.0 on iMac Intel 64 Bits).

`docker pull sonatype/nexus3`

`docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3`

Probably you have an issue in your Nexus config.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that i use M1 Silicon Mac...