# 404 Error while trying to access local klo2k/nexus3 container

Tags: docker, nexus, apple-m1, sonatype, nexus3

I'm playing around with sonatype nexus oss because jfrog's has lost support for awhile now. I have a m1 macbook pro and was told from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68990712/is-it-possible-to-run-sonatype-nexus3-docker-container-on-macos) to use [klo2k/nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/klo2k/nexus3) since my mac is arm and offical images are for amd64.

I ran the following commands:

```
docker pull klo2k/nexus3:latest
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus klo2k/nexus3:latest
```

However im getting this:[error 404 not found nexus repository manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siaJX.png)

Here are the last lines from the log:

```
2023-05-10 07:46:12,954+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.webresources.WebResourceServlet - Max-age: 30 days (2592000 seconds)
2023-05-10 07:46:12,961+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.DirectJNgineServlet - Servlet GLOBAL configuration: debug=false, providersUrl=service/extdirect, minify=false, batchRequestsMultithreadingEnabled=true, batchRequestsMinThreadsPoolSize=16, batchRequestsMaxThreadsPoolSize=80, batchRequestsMaxThreadsPerRequest=8, batchRequestsMaxThreadKeepAliveSeconds=60, gsonBuilderConfiguratorClass=org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectGsonBuilderConfigurator, dispatcherClass=com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.ssm.SsmDispatcher, jsonRequestProcessorThreadClass=org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread, contextPath=--not specified: calculated via Javascript--, createSourceFiles=true
2023-05-10 07:46:12,962+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.DirectJNgineServlet - Servlet GLOBAL configuration: registryConfiguratorClass=
2023-05-10 07:46:12,980+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.jscodegen.CodeFileGenerator - Creating source files for APIs...
2023-05-10 07:46:13,073+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.SiestaServlet - JAX-RS RuntimeDelegate: org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.internal.resteasy.SisuResteasyProviderFactory@4ea5a25
2023-05-10 07:46:13,094+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.i18n - RESTEASY008550: Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
2023-05-10 07:46:13,720+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.SiestaServlet - Initialized
2023-05-10 07:46:13,724+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Initialized
2023-05-10 07:46:13,744+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@69e75ad4{Sonatype Nexus,/,file:///opt/sonatype/nexus/public/,AVAILABLE}
2023-05-10 07:46:13,780+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@8d17cee{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2023-05-10 07:46:13,780+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @25006ms
2023-05-10 07:46:13,780+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - 
-------------------------------------------------
Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.43.0-01
-------------------------------------------------
2023-05-10 07:46:20,623+0000 INFO  [qtp231367815-105] *UNKNOWN org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager - Enabling session validation scheduler...
2023-05-10 07:46:20,642+0000 INFO  [qtp231367815-105] *UNKNOWN org.sonatype.nexus.internal.security.anonymous.AnonymousManagerImpl - Using default configuration: OrientAnonymousConfiguration{enabled=true, userId='anonymous', realmName='NexusAuthorizingRealm'}
2023-05-10 07:47:12,546+0000 INFO  [periodic-4-thread-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpclient.internal.HttpClientFacetImpl - Repository status for nuget.org-proxy changed from READY to AVAILABLE - reason n/a for n/a
2023-05-10 07:50:00,071+0000 INFO  [quartz-10-thread-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2023-05-10 07:50:00,117+0000 INFO  [quartz-10-thread-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
```

I have tried to restart the container, pull a fresh image, restart my computer, restart docker. But none of them worked

Anyone have insight on this? Thank you!